# What prevents relational databases from being optimized for writes rather than reads?

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I noticed that most of the popular relational databases systems such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, etc. are oriented towards reads rather than writes. It seems that many of these database systems cannot handle write-heavy applications (e.g. logs, telemetry, etc.) as well as they do for read-heavy applications (e.g. blogs, CMS, etc.). Is there a fundamental reason for this? Is there an inherent limitation caused by the data structures used to implement the databases?

Comment: not sure this belongs in this forum, but i would say in general, data is written once and read many times.  so thats where you would expect the optimization tradeoffs to go.

Comment: What do you mean: [a DBMS is] optimized for reads rather than writes? How are you measuring that? What use would be a DBMS that reads but doesn't write? "Cannot handle" what? You perhaps mean "logs, telemetry" are unstructured streams of data: then put structure over them. Downvoting the q because it's opinion-based.

Comment: I've used a relational database for a multitude of write-heavy applications in the Financial Tech. industry (where data is "*big*" and changes near real-time), as well as for logging, on SQL Server instances. "*It seems that many of these database systems cannot handle write-heavy applications.*" - This is just incorrect, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a well configured database can handle a write oriented model just fine, but the real problem is generally due to the database being used for an anti-pattern (such as logging or as a message queue), which it isn't really designed for (and there are frankly, better tools for the job).

There are a collection of [anti-pattern articles](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2012/04/database-as-queue-anti-pattern.html) out there, which make interesting reading when it comes to selecting the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use relational databases for logging?

Comment: For a few lines of log? A DB is just fine. But a high-volume logging destination is an anti-pattern for a relational database. There are better tools for the job, which handle the volume more gracefully, and also allow the logs to be queried more efficiently.